# VPN System Extension blocked even though it's notarized, requires user open macOS System Preferences. Is it b/c the app is not on the mac AppStore?

Tags: macos, app-store, notarize, macos-system-extension, macos-app-extension

I have an application that we're developing that provides VPN System Extension for macOS. I have successfully built, signed and notarized the app.

When we install the package the user sees this popup:

[image: System Extension Blocked popup]

*The program tried to load new system extension(s). If you want to enable these extensions, open Security & Privacy System Preferences.*

However when I download an existing VPN app from the macOS AppStore I see this popup when the extension is being installed:

[image: Sample app installing system extension]

Why am I getting the *blocked* popup when my app has been notarized? Is it because it's not coming from the AppStore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, VPNs implemented via the [NetworkExtension Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension) don't necessarily need to be installed as *System Extensions*. This is probably the distinction you're running into. You can check the list of all system extensions in the system using the following Terminal command:

```
systemextensionsctl list
0 extension(s)
```

If the "Turbo VPN" extension is not listed there, it was not installed using the [`OSSystemExtensionManager` API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemextensions/ossystemextensionmanager?language=objc).

Only *system extensions* need to go through the System Preferences user approval process.